# Setting processor governor to maximum

Tags: centos, cpu-frequency

I tried to use `cpupower` utility to manually set processor governor to performance. However, it seems that it has no effect!

```
# cpupower frequency-set -g performance
Setting cpu: 0
Setting cpu: 1
Setting cpu: 2
Setting cpu: 3
Setting cpu: 4
Setting cpu: 5
Setting cpu: 6
Setting cpu: 7
Setting cpu: 8
Setting cpu: 9
Setting cpu: 10
Setting cpu: 11
Setting cpu: 12
Setting cpu: 13
Setting cpu: 14
Setting cpu: 15
Setting cpu: 16
Setting cpu: 17
Setting cpu: 18
Setting cpu: 19
Setting cpu: 20
Setting cpu: 21
Setting cpu: 22
Setting cpu: 23
Setting cpu: 24
Setting cpu: 25
Setting cpu: 26
Setting cpu: 27
Setting cpu: 28
Setting cpu: 29
Setting cpu: 30
Setting cpu: 31
Setting cpu: 32
Setting cpu: 33
Setting cpu: 34
Setting cpu: 35
Setting cpu: 36
Setting cpu: 37
Setting cpu: 38
Setting cpu: 39
Setting cpu: 40
Setting cpu: 41
Setting cpu: 42
Setting cpu: 43
Setting cpu: 44
Setting cpu: 45
Setting cpu: 46
Setting cpu: 47
Setting cpu: 48
Setting cpu: 49
Setting cpu: 50
Setting cpu: 51
Setting cpu: 52
Setting cpu: 53
Setting cpu: 54
Setting cpu: 55
# lscpu | grep -E "(Model|CPU MHz)"
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v3 @ 2.30GHz
CPU MHz:               2150.230
# lscpu | grep -E "(Model|CPU MHz)"
Model:                 63
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v3 @ 2.30GHz
CPU MHz:               1899.027
```

Comment: What makes you think it had no effect?

Comment: From [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) : *The intel_pstate driver supports only the performance and powersave governors, but they both provide dynamic scaling.*

Comment: @terdon: As you can see in the output of lscpu, the value of CPU MHz is not constantly 2.3GHz

Comment: It's important to know also that your CPU will prevent itself from overheating if it needs to lower its temperature. Even if you enforce a 100% CPU load and change the governor. For what do you need your CPU to be at 100% ?

Comment: @Kiwy: I want to measure the time in my allocation via rdscp() so I want to be sure that frequency is constant.

Comment: It seems that powersave is constant in linux. I will try that!

Comment: please [edit] your question to add relevant information to it instead of using the comment. Also I have no idea of what is rdscp.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the governor to `performance` does not cause your CPU to constantly run at the highest MHZ possible! That would be a terrible and wasteful idea, as well as pointless. There is no reason for a CPU to run at maximum speed if it is not doing something intensive. You get no gain, and are just wasting power.

The governor will always set the speed of the CPU to the most appropriate level based on the current need and the governor setting. So, when you set it to performance, that means that it will always try to maximise performance over, for example, power conservation. This means that if you now launch a CPU-intensive task, you will see the speed of your CPU reach its maximum. But only when running something, not all the time!

This is because both the `ondemand` and the `powersave` governors provide dynamic scaling. As mentioned in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors):

> Note: The `intel_pstate` driver supports only the performance and powersave governors, but they both provide dynamic scaling. The performance governor [should give better power saving functionality than the old ondemand governor](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM3NDQ).

Comment: What you say is called "on demand" governor. That is when the processor is idle, it goes to the lowest frequency and when it has to run something it switches to max frequency. With "power save" the cpu is constantly running of the lowest frequency regardless of its state. Even in windows you will see "performance", "balanced" and "power save".

Comment: I want to test some cpu features, so I need to set the frequency to its max value

Comment: @mahmood see update. The performance governor still provides dynamic scaling. The `ondemand` governor is no longer used by modern Intel CPUs. If you need to test your CPU, run `stress` or something like that.